# Android ICS with JQuery Mobile1.0 compatibility issues

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

We are facing a very weird "Unknown chromium error: -6" issue on our HTML5 app on Android ICS (4.0). I feel the resources (JS/CSS particularly JQueryMobile) are not being loaded properly for the first time because I do not see this issue when I hit the app very next time. Does any one have any clue whats going on? Please let me know if anyone has seen this behaviour before.

App is working perfectly fine on 2.1, 2.2 and others less than 4.0

Also seeing this issue with our app. we have changed the API level to 14 so we could implement `shouldInterceptRequest()` and I'm seeing this in my log:

```
01-12 08:29:04.025: D/onPageStarted(17181): file:///android_asset/web/html/main.html
01-12 08:29:04.853: D/shouldInterceptRequest(17181): file:///android_asset/web/js/lib/jquery-1.7.js?_=1326374944864
01-12 08:29:04.861: D/onLoadResource(17181): file:///android_asset/web/js/lib/jquery-1.7.js?_=1326374944864
01-12 08:29:04.861: D/chromium(17181): Unknown chromium error: -6
01-12 08:29:04.861: D/shouldInterceptRequest(17181): file:///android_asset/web/js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0.js?_=1326374944873
01-12 08:29:04.861: D/onLoadResource(17181): file:///android_asset/web/js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0.js?_=1326374944873
01-12 08:29:04.868: D/chromium(17181): Unknown chromium error: -6
01-12 08:29:04.931: D/onPageFinished(17181): file:///android_asset/web/html/main.html
01-12 08:30:17.462: D/chromium(17119): Unknown chromium error: -6
01-12 08:30:17.462: D/chromium(17119): Unknown chromium error: -6
```

Comment: possibly the assets resolver does not like the query (used to avoid cache). you can disable it by calling `$.ajaxSetup({
 cache: true
});` before loading your libs

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're having the same problem as me. It turns out that there is a rather big bug in the browser for ICS and presumably Honeycomb based on a test. In the logcat I get the following error: Unknown chromium error: -6.

Try removing the querystring or anchor jumps and that should hopefully solve the issue (although it'll most probs screw up your functionality). There is a bug report for it [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) if anyone else is having the same issues.

Comment: For anybody following this, Steve Block from Google recently posted the following:

"To clarify, this issue has been fixed in the internal Android source, and this will be reflected in a future Android release and AOSP update."

But of course, this doesn't help those who have to support those devices that wont be updated by lazy manufacturers. At least it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried ICS and my application engine, which relies heavily on WebViews and runs flawlessly on Gingerbread seems to suffer this problem among many others ....

I also get chromium error:-6 and is certainly related to load stuff from /android_assets/

Also, pages open in iframes (that are in android assets), being the iframe opened by the main page (also in android assets) seems to cause permission problems (ie. iframe cant acess parent) ...

I'm just with ICS like 3 hours, can't provide more insight, but i will certainly follow this thread.